# Как авторизоваться на ucoz-сайте скриптом?

Tags: php, curl, парсер, ucoz

Пытаюсь через curl авторизоваться на сайте для парсинга.

Мои попытки:

Отправляю post-запрос:

```
$myCurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($myCurl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://сайт/index/sub',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,

        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
            тут параметры
        ])
    ]);
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);
```

Получаю xml в котором есть следующее:

`setTimeout("window.location.href='"+ad+"?lUqgl1'",'1000')`

Вытягиваю ключ (здесь он `lUqg1`) и передаю get запросом на главную сайта, но авторизация не происходит.

Что упустил?

Comment: Может-быть куки сохранить забыли?

Comment: Vartlok, перед отправкой ГЕТ-а парсить куки и просто через setcookie добавлять?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, зачем делать GET по адресу http://site.ucoz.ru/?lUqgl1 ?? Это простой редирект со страницы авторизации, ибо такой универсальный скрипт в ответе `window.location.href='"+ad+"?lUqgl1'` в случае успешной авторизации отправит вас на главную страницу, а не оставит на странице с формой входа.
Во-вторых, вам надо парсить заголовки `Set-Cookie` в ответе сервера, в вашем случае в `$response`. Я это дело разбил на 2 массива, с именами cookie и их значениями. Следующим вашим шагом будет формирование запроса, но надо добавить параметр:
`CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'COOKIE_NAME1=COOKIE_VALUE1; COOKIE_NAME2=COOKIE_VALUE2; '`
В моем случае это `CURLOPT_COOKIE => build_cookie_header()`. Код функции:

```
function build_cookie_header() {
    global $cookie_names;
    global $cookie_values;
    $header_value = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cookie_names); $i++) {
        $header_value .= $cookie_names[$i] . '=' . $cookie_values[$i] . '; ';
    }
    return $header_value;
}
```

т.е. формат будет такой: `name1=value1; name2=value2; ... name*=value*;`
Пробел после `;` обязателен

Answer (score 0):

У *curl* есть специальные свойства для работы с *cookie*:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, «1.txt»);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, «1.txt»);
```